Action of "AddSwaggerGen" is not called
I'm struggling with my Swagger setup for FastEndpoints. I've called this method:
WebApplicationBuilder builder = ...
builder.Services.SwaggerDocument();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options => DoMagic(options));


WebApplication app = ...
app.UseSwaggerGen();    
app.UseSwagger();    

However, DoMagic is never called. I can see nothing in the documentation which would explain why not. AddSwaggerGen() is called, I made sure of it.
I've found two other people with the same problem, but their bug was closed without comment: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/2249
Obviously this works for most people, so what could've done wrong? How do I get the action to be called?

The problem is that there are two frameworks for generating Swagger-documents: Swashbuckle and NSwag.
SwaggerDocument() and UseSwaggerGen() are from FastEndpoints and use NSwag.AddSwaggerGen() and UseSwagger() are from Swashbuckle. So depending on the order only one of these is used, and the code in the other half is never called.
So the solution is:

Compare the two frameworks and decide on one
Keep in mind that Swashbuckle is going to be removed from AspNetCore
Then remove the unused framework and implement everything anew

